# Didn't find class (...)MainActivity on path: DexPathList

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to figure out an issue with a Libgdx game I've developed. I can't seem to put it to work on the phone. It keeps giving this error and I've tried almost all solutions I've found online.
The core folder isn't present in the apk and I don't know why it isn't copying.

```
08-09 00:26:41.537: E/AndroidRuntime(24564): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-09 00:26:41.537: E/AndroidRuntime(24564): Process: games.blob, PID: 24564
08-09 00:26:41.537: E/AndroidRuntime(24564): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{games.blob/games.blob.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "games.blob.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/games.blob-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/games.blob-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
08-09 00:26:41.537: E/AndroidRuntime(24564):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2297)
08-09 00:26:41.537: E/AndroidRuntime(24564):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2441)
08-09 00:26:41.537: E/AndroidRuntime(24564):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151)
08-09 00:26:41.537: E/AndroidRuntime(24564):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
08-09 00:26:41.537: E/AndroidRuntime(24564):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
08-09 00:26:41.537: E/AndroidRuntime(24564):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
08-09 00:26:41.537: E/AndroidRuntime(24564):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5345)
08-09 00:26:41.537: E/AndroidRuntime(24564):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-09 00:26:41.537: E/AndroidRuntime(24564):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-09 00:26:41.537: E/AndroidRuntime(24564):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
08-09 00:26:41.537: E/AndroidRuntime(24564):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
08-09 00:26:41.537: E/AndroidRuntime(24564):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-09 00:26:41.537: E/AndroidRuntime(24564): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "games.blob.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/games.blob-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/games.blob-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
08-09 00:26:41.537: E/AndroidRuntime(24564):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
08-09 00:26:41.537: E/AndroidRuntime(24564):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
08-09 00:26:41.537: E/AndroidRuntime(24564):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
08-09 00:26:41.537: E/AndroidRuntime(24564):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
08-09 00:26:41.537: E/AndroidRuntime(24564):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
08-09 00:26:41.537: E/AndroidRuntime(24564):    ... 11 more
```

My Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>         
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="games.blob"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <application
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:allowBackup="false"  >
        <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="Blob"
                android:screenOrientation="landscape"
                android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: What are you using to build your app? The error is implying that your apk does not include your compiled source classes.

Comment: I'm using eclipse and the project was generated with libgdx java based framework.